# Does choice of endianness have impact on file size in UTF-16 and why?

Tags: endianness, filesize, utf-16

Does choice of endianness have impact on file size in UTF-16 and why? I can't figure out how this should be the case but wanted to be sure. Thanks

Comment: Endianness affects the order of the bytes, not their number. The only plausible size difference could occur if an encoder decides to add or remove a byte order marker (BOM), which is two bytes.

Comment: 1. Which of the orders is default nowadays and do I have to specialize if a  BOM is used? I read, that the decoder doesn't print the BOM, because it uses an special codepoint FEFF/FFFE. 2. How could I even manually add a BOM in that case? Greetings

Comment: [Wikipedia has the skinny on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte_order_encoding_schemes). In brief: there is no universal default; it'll depend on your platform and the decoder. Manually adding a BOM means adding two bytes at the beginning, but of course you do need to know the actual endianness before you can do that.

Comment: This goes a little beyond my original question, but just in case you can afford another minute: Do you know any way to force my editor (I'm using nano at the moment) to show me the internal representation of the characters and change it? Do I have to trick it by e.g. redirecting an od or are there any recommended (preferably command line) applications for working on text files on a bit/byte-level? Thanks for your time

Comment: Sorry, not a nano user, or for that matter a big user of UTF-16 files on Linux. A question like that could find a home on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). You can probably determine the current encoding with `file` and change it (if necessary) with `recode`, see for example [this question](https://superuser.com/q/116907) (with appropriate changes for your case).

Comment: I'm drifting away anyway.. ;) I'll try to concentrate on my exam preparation again and try to figure this out afterwards. You were a great help! Have a nice weekend!